# How many days until the population doubles

Tags: calculus, functions, indefinite-integrals

I have a function called $P(t)$ that is the number of the population at time $t$. $t$ being in days.

We know the growth rate is $P'(t) = 2t + 6$

We also know that $P(0) = 100$. How many days till the population doubles?

edit: $P(t) = t^2 + 6t$
edit: $P(t) = t^2 + 6t = 200$
edit: $t^2 + 6t - 200 = 0$

Comment: You're aware of $dP/dt$, so what could $P(t)$ be? Also, what do you think the significance of $N(0)$ is?

Comment: Sorry N(0) is supposed to P(0). I'm confused on how to even start this question.

Comment: You want to integrate $P'(t)$ to get $P(t)$ (using $P(0)$) to get the integration constant), and then solve $P(t)=2P(0)$.

Comment: Ah, I just integrated this. I see, so I make $P(t) = 200$?

Comment: @raz789 ok, a typo fine. So you have all the tools to complete the integral and the intital condition is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You integrated (almost) correctly; however
\begin{eqnarray}
P(t) &=& \int 2t + 6 dt \\
     &=& t^{2}+6t+C
\end{eqnarray}
$C$ is a constant of integration; now your intital condition is $P(0)=100$ meaning at $t=0$ the population was $100$. Plug it into the formula for $P(t)$
\begin{eqnarray}
P(0)  &=& 100 \\
      &=& 0^{2} + 6(0) + C \\
      &=& C
\end{eqnarray}
Meaning $C=100$; therefore
\begin{equation}
P(t) = t^{2}+6t+100
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You are given $P'(t)=\frac {dP}{dt}=2t+6$  Integrate both sides with respect to $t$ to get $P(t)$  At this stage you will have a constant of integration which you can assess using your data on $P(0)$  What is the population when the doubling is over?  Solve $P(t)=$this

Comment: Thanks I think I got it out. Is it possible to get two answers? $P(t) = t^2 + 6t = 200$ This should give a quadratic, correct? edit: nvm solved it.

Comment: You forgot the constant of integration.  Your $P(t)$ has $P(0)=0$  Since the population is monotonically growing (at least for $t \ge 0$), there should be only one positive solution.